# Biholomorphic functions on the whole complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

The question is the following: are there some other biholomorphic functions on the whole complex plane except to polynomials of the degree 1? I don't think so, but i cannot find the proof.
(I mean functions that are bijektiv and holomorphich with a holomorphich inverse on the whole plane.)
Has somebody an idea? Thanks.

Comment: Use Casorati-Weierstraß to show that non-polynomials are never injective,and the fundamental theorem of algebra that among the polynomials, only those of degree 1 are injective.

Comment: How exactly does Casorati-Weierstraß help? How can I show that the function is not injective if it is not a polynomial?

Comment: If $f$ is entire and not polynomial, then $f(1/z)$ has an essential singularity at $0$.

Comment: Thanks, but this is actually clear for me. I don't see how i can obtain non-injectivity from this. The  Casorati-Weierstraß says only that we can approximate every possible value. But not that we can get every value multiple times.

Comment: You also need to use the open mapping theorem: Take two disjoint, open sets $U,V$ such that $U$ is a punctured neighborhood of $0$. Then $f(V)$ is dense and $f(U)$ is open, so they intersect, which they shouldn't if $f(1/x)$ was injective.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that $z/f(1/z)$ is holomorphic around $z=0$, thus it is analytic, with a zero of order $k$ at $z=0$, which implies that $f(1/z)$ has a pole of order $k-1$ at $z=0$ so that $f(1/z)-P(1/z)$ is analytic at $z=0$ for some polynomial.

Both $f(z)-P(z)$ and $f(1/z)-P(1/z)$ are analytic thus bounded for $|z|\le 2$.

Let $z_0\in \Bbb{C}$ maximizing $|f(z)-P(z)|$. The maximum modulus principle implies that  $f(z)-P(z)$ is constant near $z_0$, thus everywhere.

So $f(z)=P(z)+C$ and for being injective we need $\deg(P)=1$.

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't understand one thing. Why is 0 not a singularity for zf(1/z)?

Comment: $f$ is non-zero for $|z|$ large enough so $g(z)=z/f(1/z)$  is holomorphic for $0<|z|<r$, then $f(\infty)=\infty$ so $g(z)=z/f(1/z)$ is continuous, and $g'(0)=\lim_{z\to 0}g(z)/z= 1/f(1/0)= 0$ thus $g$ is holomorphic.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!